# Google Sheets - Combining COUNTBACKGROUNDCOLOR and COUNTIF formulas

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, conditional-formatting, countif

I want to count the amount a certain text(aus) appears in a column, but I only want to search the rows that have one specific color. I have the two seperate working formulas but haven't been able to combine them succesfully yet. Anybody an idea how to do this :) ? Here are the 2 formulas i have:

=COUNTBACKGROUNDCOLOR("J2:J361";"A2")

=COUNTIF(J2:J361; "*aus")

Comment: how did the cells come to have that color? was there some reason you chose a certain color for a certain cell?  If so, couldn't *that reason* be used to count the cells rather than the color?

Comment: Hi MK, thank you so much for your fast reply and brilliant idea, didn't think about this yet. All the colored rows have indeed also a checkbox ticked with true, so yes this could be used as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears as though you are using a script to implement your own function of COUNTBACKGROUNDCOLOR(). If this is the case you cannot combine the two functions as it stands since it is a user defined function. As MattKing pointed out maybe count the cells with your data AND the method used to declare the color (checkboxes). Example:

Conditional formatting applied to cells that highlight the cell green if adjacent checkbox is TRUE.

[image]

Formula used

[image]

Notice the answer is 2 and not 3 because from your formula you are only looking for wildcards before "aus" and Cell D4 contains a "?" at the END ("what is aus?")

[image]

Comment: Hi kevin, Thank you very much for your answer, exactly what I was searching for and indeed this did the trick!

Comment: @BartMeijer, if it helped you, consider accepting the answer.

Comment: @Kevin-p Done 